# Problem on displaying the results on my query

Tags: php

Hello this is my query. I want to show the titles of posts that have fullfil the following but t doesn't show anything, I don't know. Thank you!
Also, is there another way to show the results, more wordpress-like?

```
<?php 

$theposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE ID IN
(
   SELECT DISTINCT post_id
   FROM $wpdb->postmeta
   WHERE meta_key = 'extra1' AND meta_value = 'test'
)");

foreach ($theposts as $thepost) {
echo $thepost->post_title;

}
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you show the error?

Comment: It doesn't display anything. My metakey and metavalue is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$theposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE ID IN
(
   SELECT DISTINCT post_id
   FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
   WHERE meta_key = 'extra1' AND meta_value = 'test'
)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written "WHERE" twice on line 4 of your code. If that doesn't fix it then can you post the error your seeing please

Comment: I have updated it replacing a command with `echo $thepost->post_title;` and now it doesn't display anything